# SocketException in .net core 3.1 against SQS endpoint but not in Python or CLI

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, .net-core

I'm getting an exception when running the following little console app on a windows 2016 ec2 instance (.NET Core 3.1):
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond." System.Exception {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.SQS;
using Amazon.SQS.Model;
using Amazon.S3;
namespace TestSqsConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            AmazonSQSClient _client = new AmazonSQSClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            string url =  (await _client.GetQueueUrlAsync(new GetQueueUrlRequest { QueueName = "my-queue"  }))?.QueueUrl;
            Console.WriteLine(url);
        }
    }
}
```

What's odd is that I can run this command through the CLI and it works fine:

```
aws sqs get-queue-url --queue-name my-queue
```

I also tried to do a simple S3 ListObjectsV2Async command from my .NET Core app just to make sure there wasn't some broader issue and that worked. I tried a couple of different versions of the AWS SDK for .NET and tried a few different version of .NET Core framework. With .NET 4.7.2 I got a slightly more useful exception that said:

SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.163.7.205:443  This is the IP of the SQS Endpoint in my VPC. The EC2 instance and the endpoint are in different subnets but that should be ok I thought. Lastly, I wrote the equivalent app in Python and that works fine so I'm very confused.

Answer (score 0):

well, we figured out what was wrong but it raises other questions that I don't understand. It turned out that the security group for the SQS Endpoint did not have any inbound rules specified. Once we add the appropriate rules, the .NET core app started working. But how does the CLI or the python app work without these inbound rules is a mystery